# What is the name of the series about human beings with genetically modified police women?

Tags: story-identification

They speak English. I think the hair was dark brown and skin colour is white. The series starts with a genetically modified person being killed.

There is a female police force that has been genetically modified, possibly making them smarter( or something else). They were beautiful and healthy because of their genetic superiority.

The woman worked with the human cops. She's been a cop for personal reasons. Because she has a genetic superiority she could be lawyer or doctor like the others.

There was even a different name for the genetically modified people. The show was very good, but I forgot the name.

They had their own group. They even made fun of being a female cop. They asked why she become a cop.

Series from 2015 or earlier.

Comment: What country was the series made in, when was it broadcast?

Comment: [Painkiller Jane](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0866432/) maybe?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Is there any more details you can give us about the program, what year it was from, what channel may have broadcast it, and any extra details about the show. If you remember anything else either comment or [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/149826/edit) your post to add in the details. Also, feel free to take the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I have not watched for years. From 2015 or earlier. The woman worked with the human cops. She's been a cop for personal reasons. Because she has a genetic superiority she could be lawyer or doctor like the others.

Comment: That last bit made me think of [Psycho-Pass](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13601/Psycho-Pass).

Comment: Gah, this seems very familiar, particularly the part of her choosing to be a cop when she could be a lawyer or doctor, but I can't place it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Almost Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_Human_(TV_series))*

> Minka Kelly as Detective Valerie Stahl, another detective serving under Captain Maldonado, and a love interest for Kennex. She is a Chrome, a human genetically engineered for beauty, excellence and success. Other Chromes consider her choice of profession to be a waste of potential.

[image: Det. Valerie Stahl]

The first episode does not begin with the death of a Chrome, but episodes 10 and 12 of the series do:

> Two "chrome" (genetically engineered) girls are killed by a new designer drug, which is related to a previous accidental drowning of another girl. Kennex and Stahl (a "chrome" herself) investigate the case, which leads them to the Mendel Institute, where many students, except two, are "chromes". When they find a sample of the drug, the pharmaceutical printer used leads them to a former Mendel Institute student, who acknowledges making the drug, called "Vero", but swears the printer was hacked to create the fatal doses. The clues finally lead them to the mother of the first girl—who had killed herself after taking Vero—and who hired the hacker for revenge. Meanwhile, Kennex uses drugs and a black-market Recollectionist doctor to try to remember more things about his traitorous ex-girlfriend Anna Moore and the ambush where he lost his leg, despite Dorian and Maldonado's warnings. He finally remembers a detail which leads him to discover his home had been bugged.

....

> After a healthy chrome is reported to have died from natural causes, Detective Stahl suspects foul play. Upon further investigation, they find that the dead chrome has the DNA of seven other victims all with good looking facial features. Kennex and Dorian are called in to track down a serial killer (Michael Eklund) who has been using a nanobot surgical system to take facial features from his victims and transferring them to his face for the woman he loves, who he has been communicating with via online conversations (Only to learn upon meeting her that she is blind). Kennex makes a move and is about to ask Detective Stahl out for a drink, only to find out that he is too late.

However, [Wikipedia's talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Almost_Human_(TV_series)) mentions that Fox aired the episodes out of order, so it's entirely possible that you saw one of those first.

Comment: I don't know if it's what the OP was looking for but that's definitely where it was trigging memories from me.  Just the whole robot A-plot of the series made instant recognition hard.

Comment: The OP's initial description is "genetically modified policewomen", which wouldn't fit, since this is primarily about the robot policemen, but then again, most of their description indicates there only one such policewoman and the rest feel like there are better things to do. :) So I'm happy enough with my answer.

Comment: Thank you. As long as I remember, I wrote it. Thank you again. :)

Comment: I watched this show and it does hit on all of the OPs points. "Painkiller Jane" is another good thought but I don't recall much discussion that she was wasting herself being a cop, which DEFINITELY was a plot point in Almost Human.